# Unflatten by convention with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper-10

In my project I'm trying to use automapper to unflatten my command objects to my domain objects by convention as much as possible.
It works when I explicitly map the two members in the mapping profile, but [according to the automapper documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html) I think this should also work by convention.
I created [a dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/amdm5J) to demonstrate the minimal case.

Related questions end up with people explicitly adding the mapping, but that kind of goes against what Automapper is built for and contradicts the documentation, no?
It doesn't work with flattening either, so the reversemap is a red herring I think.

The mapping

```
public class Mapping: Profile
{
    public Mapping()
    {
        this.CreateMap<CreateSelectionCommand, Selection>();
        // .ForMember(selection => selection.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.SelectionName))
        .reverseMap()
    }
}
```

What I expect to work

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldMapName()
{
    var cmd = new CreateSelectionCommand {SelectionName = "selectionName"};
    var selection = _mapper.Map<Selection>(cmd);

    Assert.Equal(cmd.SelectionName, selection.Name); <== selection.Name == ""
}
```

Classes for context

```
public class Selection
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CreateSelectionCommand
{
    public string SelectionName { get; set; }
}
```

Did I misread the docs or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flattening is about mapping nested "complex" objects to properties on "higher" level i.e. in your case if `CreateSelectionCommand` had property `Selection` of type which had `Name` property it would be mapped to `SelectionName` in destination type (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FlPu7U)).

You can try to use [prefixes](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#recognizing-pre-postfixes) by adding:

```
cfg.RecognizePrefixes("Selection");
```

to your configuration (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S4IzPP)) but I doubt that it is suitable option for convention based handling.

Also it seems that you can add custom name convention using `ISourceToDestinationNameMapper` and `AddMemberConfiguration`:

```
class TypeNamePrefixedSourceToDestinationNameMapper : ISourceToDestinationNameMapper
{
    public MemberInfo GetMatchingMemberInfo(IGetTypeInfoMembers getTypeInfoMembers, TypeDetails typeInfo,
        Type destType,
        Type destMemberType, string nameToSearch)
    {
        return getTypeInfoMembers.GetMemberInfos(typeInfo)
            .FirstOrDefault(mi => mi.Name == destType.Name + nameToSearch);
    }
}

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddMemberConfiguration().AddName<TypeNamePrefixedSourceToDestinationNameMapper>();

    // ...
}
```

At least it works in this simple case, see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qWBdI6).

Comment: Good explanation and suggestions. I'll see how far I can get with the convention. Otherwise I'll stick with explicitly defining the mapping

Comment: @BorisCallens was glad to help! Also I was able to do something similar (but looking a bit more hacky) by adding some property mappings in `cfg.ForAllMaps`.